# Why is IOptionsMonitor not picking up changes made in other files than appsettings.json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-6.0

I have a .NET 6.0 application. I want to add a custom configuration file (custom.json). As you can see in the code, reloadOnChange is true.

During runtime I change the value from `testvalue` to `someothervalue`. In the endpoint I use the IOptionsMonitor, which should actually pick up changes if I understood the documentation correctly. So my expectation is that the API now returns `someothervalue`, but for some reason it does always return the initial value (`testvalue`). I also tried using IOptionsSnapshot, but it makes no difference.

When I move the setting to appsettings.json it works as expected. My question is, what am I doing wrong?

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile(".\\custom.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

builder.Services.Configure<MyOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MyOptions)));

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapGet("/api/test", async context =>
    {
        var optionsMonitor = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<MyOptions>>();

        await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(optionsMonitor.CurrentValue);
    })
.WithName("Test");

app.Run();

internal class MyOptions
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

custom.json:

```json
{
    "MyOptions": {
        "Value": "testvalue"
    }
}
```

Comment: What OS are you using? Also JFYI works for me if change path to `"custom.json"`.

Comment: Windows 10. You are right, that works also for me. Thanks a lot! Even though I don't quite understand why. It manages to read the configuration at startup, but not on change.
PS: If you post your comment as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Was glad to help. Though I don't think it is worthy an answer cause it will heavily lack on explanations.